# PSFB - Asymetric current at the secondary

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, diagram, phase-shift

At the 3rd step of the PSFB cycle, the current at the secondary is not shared equally by the two windings that it would be if it were a full bridge. Does anyone can explain why it is not the case ? And why only the variation of the two output current is shared by the two windings ? I am not sure that the sign of the following pictures are correct. It should be Iout - deltaIout/2 and - deltaIout/2 as no energy is being transfered. I probably do an error ?

[image]

The same appears from this diagram :

[image]

This one seems to be better for the same architecture :

[image]

Here are the links :

https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucc28950.pdf?ts=1642537671521&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FUCC28950
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucc2895.pdf?ts=1642523455070&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FUCC2895
https://training.ti.com/how-design-multi-kw-dcdc-converters-electric-vehicles-evs-how-psfb-works

Have a nice day ,

------------------------------------E D I T --------------------------------

Well I have not still find the answer but by documenting my self I found something well weird :

Here is the simulation that "A concerned citizen" have done. (Thank you). It is a bit modified according to my needs and we clearly see a negative current :

[image]

[image]

Then I was looking something else and I found this comment on the video (linked below) ...

[image]

It seems to be pretty complicated to avoid a negative current with SR ...
And I think it is right that it can do a voltage spike as there is no way for the current to go ... There is nothing to limit the rise of voltage when the current is negative...

I am probably missing something...

Here is the last simulation :

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 3192 1840
WIRE 2272 112 2064 112
WIRE 2784 112 2272 112
WIRE 2064 128 2064 112
WIRE 2784 128 2784 112
WIRE 1968 208 1904 208
WIRE 2016 208 1968 208
WIRE 2880 208 2832 208
WIRE 2944 208 2880 208
WIRE 640 224 496 224
WIRE 704 224 640 224
WIRE 848 224 704 224
WIRE 1296 224 848 224
WIRE 1360 224 1296 224
WIRE 1488 224 1360 224
WIRE 496 240 496 224
WIRE 1488 240 1488 224
WIRE 2240 272 2176 272
WIRE 2384 272 2320 272
WIRE 1968 288 1904 288
WIRE 2064 288 2064 224
WIRE 2064 288 1968 288
WIRE 2784 288 2784 224
WIRE 2880 288 2784 288
WIRE 2944 288 2880 288
WIRE 704 304 704 288
WIRE 704 304 640 304
WIRE 1296 304 1296 288
WIRE 1360 304 1296 304
WIRE 2064 352 2064 288
WIRE 2176 352 2176 272
WIRE 2176 352 2064 352
WIRE 2240 352 2176 352
WIRE 2384 352 2384 272
WIRE 2384 352 2320 352
WIRE 2496 352 2384 352
WIRE 2640 352 2576 352
WIRE 2784 352 2784 288
WIRE 2784 352 2720 352
WIRE -528 384 -544 384
WIRE -416 384 -464 384
WIRE -192 384 -416 384
WIRE -80 384 -192 384
WIRE 816 384 752 384
WIRE 960 384 896 384
WIRE -192 416 -192 384
WIRE -176 416 -192 416
WIRE -80 416 -112 416
WIRE -544 448 -544 384
WIRE -464 448 -464 416
WIRE -464 448 -544 448
WIRE -96 448 -112 448
WIRE 496 464 496 304
WIRE 640 464 640 304
WIRE 640 464 496 464
WIRE 752 464 752 384
WIRE 752 464 640 464
WIRE 816 464 752 464
WIRE 960 464 960 384
WIRE 960 464 896 464
WIRE 1072 464 960 464
WIRE 1216 464 1152 464
WIRE 1360 464 1360 304
WIRE 1360 464 1296 464
WIRE 1488 464 1488 304
WIRE 1488 464 1360 464
WIRE 2064 464 2064 352
WIRE 2784 464 2784 352
WIRE -96 496 -96 448
WIRE -80 496 -96 496
WIRE -464 528 -464 448
WIRE -80 528 -464 528
WIRE 1968 544 1904 544
WIRE 2016 544 1968 544
WIRE 2896 544 2832 544
WIRE 2960 544 2896 544
WIRE -416 608 -416 384
WIRE -400 608 -416 608
WIRE -320 608 -336 608
WIRE -80 608 -320 608
WIRE 496 608 496 464
WIRE 640 608 640 464
WIRE 704 608 640 608
WIRE 1360 608 1360 464
WIRE 1360 608 1296 608
WIRE 1488 608 1488 464
WIRE 1968 624 1904 624
WIRE 2064 624 2064 560
WIRE 2064 624 1968 624
WIRE 2480 624 2064 624
WIRE 2784 624 2784 560
WIRE 2784 624 2480 624
WIRE 2896 624 2784 624
WIRE 2960 624 2896 624
WIRE -320 640 -320 608
WIRE -256 640 -320 640
WIRE -80 640 -192 640
WIRE -96 672 -192 672
WIRE 496 688 496 672
WIRE 640 688 496 688
WIRE 704 688 704 672
WIRE 704 688 640 688
WIRE 784 688 704 688
WIRE 1296 688 1296 672
WIRE 1296 688 784 688
WIRE 1360 688 1296 688
WIRE 1488 688 1488 672
WIRE 1488 688 1360 688
WIRE -96 720 -96 672
WIRE -80 720 -96 720
WIRE -336 752 -336 640
WIRE -80 752 -336 752
WIRE 880 832 656 832
WIRE 2288 832 2064 832
WIRE 656 944 656 912
WIRE 704 944 656 944
WIRE 992 944 784 944
WIRE 1040 944 992 944
WIRE 1056 944 1040 944
WIRE 2064 944 2064 912
WIRE 2112 944 2064 944
WIRE 2656 944 2192 944
WIRE 2704 944 2656 944
WIRE 2720 944 2704 944
WIRE 656 976 656 944
WIRE 2064 976 2064 944
WIRE 1056 992 1056 944
WIRE 2720 992 2720 944
WIRE 992 1056 992 944
WIRE 2656 1056 2656 944
WIRE 656 1104 656 1056
WIRE 720 1104 656 1104
WIRE 880 1104 880 832
WIRE 880 1104 816 1104
WIRE 2064 1104 2064 1056
WIRE 2288 1104 2288 832
WIRE 720 1184 720 1168
WIRE 720 1184 656 1184
WIRE 816 1184 816 1168
WIRE 816 1184 720 1184
WIRE 880 1184 816 1184
WIRE 992 1184 992 1120
WIRE 992 1184 880 1184
WIRE 1056 1184 1056 1072
WIRE 1056 1184 992 1184
WIRE 1968 1184 1904 1184
WIRE 2016 1184 1968 1184
WIRE 2384 1184 2336 1184
WIRE 2448 1184 2384 1184
WIRE 2656 1184 2656 1120
WIRE 2720 1184 2720 1072
WIRE 2720 1184 2656 1184
WIRE 1968 1264 1904 1264
WIRE 2064 1264 2064 1200
WIRE 2064 1264 1968 1264
WIRE 2176 1264 2064 1264
WIRE 2288 1264 2288 1200
WIRE 2288 1264 2176 1264
WIRE 2384 1264 2288 1264
WIRE 2448 1264 2384 1264
FLAG 592 288 0
FLAG 592 672 0
FLAG 1408 672 0
FLAG 1408 288 0
FLAG 192 256 0
FLAG 784 688 0
FLAG -16 384 a
FLAG 592 240 a
FLAG 592 624 b
FLAG -16 496 b
FLAG -16 608 c
FLAG -16 720 d
FLAG 1408 240 c
FLAG 1408 624 d
FLAG 928 1168 0
FLAG 928 1120 f
FLAG 608 1168 0
FLAG 608 1120 e
FLAG -544 848 b
FLAG -544 880 c
FLAG -480 848 e
FLAG -544 992 a
FLAG -544 1024 d
FLAG -480 992 f
FLAG 1056 1184 0
FLAG 1040 944 o
FLAG 848 224 v
FLAG 192 176 v
FLAG 2720 1184 0
FLAG 2704 944 o1
FLAG 2272 112 v
FLAG 1856 272 0
FLAG 1856 224 a
FLAG 1856 608 0
FLAG 1856 560 b
FLAG 2480 624 0
FLAG 3008 608 0
FLAG 3008 560 d
FLAG 2992 272 0
FLAG 2992 224 c
FLAG 1856 1248 0
FLAG 1856 1200 e
FLAG 2496 1248 0
FLAG 2496 1200 f
FLAG 2176 1264 0
SYMBOL sw 640 320 M180
SYMATTR InstName S1
SYMBOL diode 688 288 M180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D1
SYMBOL sw 640 704 M180
SYMATTR InstName S2
SYMBOL diode 688 672 M180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D2
SYMBOL sw 1360 320 R180
SYMATTR InstName S3
SYMBOL diode 1312 288 R180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D3
SYMBOL sw 1360 704 R180
SYMATTR InstName S4
SYMBOL diode 1312 672 R180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D4
SYMBOL ind2 800 480 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 5 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName L1
SYMATTR Value {Lp}
SYMATTR Type ind
SYMBOL voltage 192 160 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value 390
SYMBOL Digital\\and -496 336 R0
WINDOW 3 -329 67 Left 2
SYMATTR Value td={1/(2*Fsw)} ic=0
SYMATTR InstName A1
SYMBOL Digital\\and -144 368 R0
WINDOW 3 -113 119 Left 2
SYMATTR Value td={DELAB}
SYMATTR InstName A2
SYMBOL Digital\\and -48 336 R0
WINDOW 3 -23 108 Left 2
SYMATTR Value tau={1/(Fsw*1000)}
SYMATTR InstName A3
SYMBOL Digital\\and -48 448 R0
WINDOW 3 -23 108 Left 2
SYMATTR Value tau={1/(Fsw*1000)}
SYMATTR InstName A4
SYMBOL Digital\\and -368 560 R0
WINDOW 3 -426 116 Left 2
SYMATTR Value td={(2*(1-(1-D)/2)-1)/(2*Fsw)}
SYMATTR InstName A5
SYMBOL Digital\\and -224 592 R0
WINDOW 3 -23 108 Left 2
SYMATTR Value td={DELCD}
SYMATTR InstName A6
SYMBOL Digital\\and -48 560 R0
WINDOW 3 -23 108 Left 2
SYMATTR Value tau={1/(Fsw*1000)}
SYMATTR InstName A7
SYMBOL Digital\\and -48 672 R0
WINDOW 3 -23 108 Left 2
SYMATTR Value tau={1/(Fsw*1000)}
SYMATTR InstName A8
SYMBOL ind2 672 928 R180
WINDOW 0 36 80 Left 2
WINDOW 3 36 40 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName L2
SYMATTR Value {Ls}
SYMATTR Type ind
SYMBOL ind2 672 1072 R180
WINDOW 0 36 80 Left 2
WINDOW 3 36 40 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName L3
SYMATTR Value {Ls}
SYMATTR Type ind
SYMBOL sw 880 1200 R180
SYMATTR InstName S5
SYMBOL diode 832 1168 R180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D5
SYMBOL sw 656 1200 M180
SYMATTR InstName S6
SYMBOL diode 704 1168 M180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D6
SYMBOL Digital\\or -512 800 R0
WINDOW 3 -8 30 Left 2
SYMATTR Value tau={1/(Fsw*1000)}
SYMATTR InstName A9
SYMBOL cap 976 1056 R0
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value 7500µ rser=10m
SYMBOL Digital\\or -512 944 R0
WINDOW 3 -8 30 Left 2
SYMATTR Value tau={1/(Fsw*1000)}
SYMATTR InstName A10
SYMBOL res 1040 976 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value {12/50}
SYMBOL ind 800 400 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 5 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName L4
SYMATTR Value 4m52
SYMBOL ind 1056 480 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 5 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName L5
SYMATTR Value 7.5µ
SYMBOL ind 1200 480 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 5 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName L6
SYMATTR Value 26µ
SYMBOL cap 1472 240 R0
SYMATTR InstName C2
SYMATTR Value 70p
SYMBOL cap 1472 608 R0
SYMATTR InstName C3
SYMATTR Value 70p
SYMBOL cap 480 608 R0
SYMATTR InstName C4
SYMATTR Value 70p
SYMBOL cap 480 240 R0
SYMATTR InstName C5
SYMATTR Value 70p
SYMBOL ind 800 928 R90
WINDOW 0 5 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName L7
SYMATTR Value 0.2µ
SYMBOL ind2 2224 368 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 5 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName L8
SYMATTR Value {Lp}
SYMATTR Type ind
SYMBOL ind2 2080 928 R180
WINDOW 0 36 80 Left 2
WINDOW 3 36 40 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName L9
SYMATTR Value {Ls}
SYMATTR Type ind
SYMBOL ind2 2080 1072 R180
WINDOW 0 36 80 Left 2
WINDOW 3 36 40 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName L10
SYMATTR Value {Ls}
SYMATTR Type ind
SYMBOL cap 2640 1056 R0
SYMATTR InstName C6
SYMATTR Value 7500µ rser=10m
SYMBOL res 2704 976 R0
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value {12/50}
SYMBOL ind 2224 288 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 5 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName L11
SYMATTR Value 4m52
SYMBOL ind 2480 368 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 5 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName L12
SYMATTR Value 7.5µ
SYMBOL ind 2624 368 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 5 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName L13
SYMATTR Value 26µ
SYMBOL ind 2208 928 R90
WINDOW 0 5 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName L14
SYMATTR Value 0.2µ
SYMBOL g 1904 192 R0
SYMATTR InstName G1
SYMATTR Value 12
SYMBOL res 1952 192 R0
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL nmos 2016 464 R0
WINDOW 3 57 51 Left 2
SYMATTR Value STP8NM60
SYMATTR InstName M3
SYMBOL g 1904 528 R0
SYMATTR InstName G2
SYMATTR Value 12
SYMBOL res 1952 528 R0
SYMATTR InstName R4
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL g 2960 528 M0
SYMATTR InstName G3
SYMATTR Value 12
SYMBOL res 2912 528 M0
SYMATTR InstName R5
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL g 2944 192 M0
SYMATTR InstName G4
SYMATTR Value 12
SYMBOL res 2896 192 M0
SYMATTR InstName R6
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL nmos 2016 1104 R0
WINDOW 3 57 51 Left 2
SYMATTR Value IRFH5020
SYMATTR InstName M5
SYMBOL g 1904 1168 R0
SYMATTR InstName G5
SYMATTR Value 12
SYMBOL res 1952 1168 R0
SYMATTR InstName R7
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL nmos 2336 1104 M0
WINDOW 3 57 51 Left 2
SYMATTR Value IRFH5020
SYMATTR InstName M6
SYMBOL g 2448 1168 M0
SYMATTR InstName G6
SYMATTR Value 12
SYMBOL res 2400 1168 M0
SYMATTR InstName R8
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL nmos 2016 128 R0
WINDOW 3 57 51 Left 2
SYMATTR Value STP8NM60
SYMATTR InstName M1
SYMBOL nmos 2832 128 M0
WINDOW 3 57 51 Left 2
SYMATTR Value STP8NM60
SYMATTR InstName M2
SYMBOL nmos 2832 464 M0
WINDOW 3 57 51 Left 2
SYMATTR Value STP8NM60
SYMATTR InstName M4
TEXT -528 -40 Left 2 !.model sw sw ron=50m roff=0.1g vt=0.5 vh=-0.5 ; level=2 oneway ilimit=1k\n.model d d ron=50m roff=0.1g vfwd=0.45 vrev=1k epsilon=50m revepsilon=1
TEXT 952 872 Left 2 !.tran 3m
TEXT -520 -280 Left 2 ;https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucc28950.pdf?ts=1642537671521&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FUCC28950\nhttps://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucc2895.pdf?ts=1642523455070&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FUCC2895\nhttps://training.ti.com/how-design-multi-kw-dcdc-converters-electric-vehicles-evs-how-psfb-works
TEXT -768 224 Left 2 ;tau = Output RC time constant
TEXT -776 256 Left 2 ;td = Output propagation delay
TEXT -528 -176 Left 2 !.param Fsw = 100k DELAB = 100n DELCD = 100n D=0.8 Lp = 1 Ns = 1 Np = 21 Ls = Lp*Ns**2/Np**2
TEXT -688 920 Left 2 ;Manque la simulation de DELAF et DELBE, utile pour diminuer les pertes
TEXT 928 768 Left 2 !K L1 L2 L3 1
TEXT 720 888 Left 2 ;2u
TEXT 2352 656 Left 2 !K2 L8 L9 L10 1
TEXT 2128 888 Left 2 ;2u
LINE Normal 192 1072 192 320 2
```

Have a nice day,

Comment: Did you forget the link to the document?

Comment: You re right as usual :)

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen. Thank you for your simulation ! Could you please send it ? I will be really happy to better understand how you simulate a phase shift "controller". Then there is still a question why the current is not shared equally by the two winding ? Why each windings have just not "(Iout+deltaIout)/2" current value ?

Comment: There is also something which troubles me. It exists some PSFB without "syncrhonous" rectification at the secondaries, so when there are diodes instead of MOSFET/GaN how can the current be negative ?

Comment: @Jess If you really want to be baffled, check the currents in the MOSFET version. For example, I changed the source to be `24`, the transistors `IRFH5015`, both the primary and the secondaries `100u`, `R=10, L=20u, C=10u`, added some overdone snubbers on both secondaries (`1n rser=100`), and then watch the [differences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOH5A.png) (here the primary currents). One of the problems is that in the VCSW version, the VCSW allows reverse conduction if the command is high. ([schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPjby.png)).

Comment: Well it is pretty bad all these things , it diverges from the theoritical model from TI. I am not working at TI but I have all my confidence to them ^^ I am baffled. Just question why do you put current source to switch on and off your MOSFET ? and why not a voltage source like a newbie like me would do !

Comment: @Jess The main reason is explained in the help (*LTspice > Circuit Elements > E. ...*, bottom note). In addition, I vaguely recall (can't remember where) that, due to the modified nodal analysis of LTspice, voltage sources that are off ground may cause problems (something about matrix inversion? I really can't remember). So the floating drivers should be better behaved. That's not to say all voltage sources are cursed, just that I'm playing it safe. The more complicated the circuit, the more chances there are that something will run amok -- no need for me to help that.

Comment: Thank you for this :)

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I do not know what is explaining your waveforms and when I did your schematic I have the same weird things than you but in my simulation which is almost the same than you, I have not any troubles ... I have the same waveform than If i am considering a VCSW version. I will edit my post to send you my simulation if you want. I will also start a bounty ^^

Comment: @Jess You used different values, most probably you have a specific goal in mind. Mine were some random values (though not just thrown in there, blindly) so it's probably the reason why. I see you used the additional series inductor with the primary (but why two? why not "marry" them?), and you used the `Lp, Ls` as the underlying coupling inductors -- did you mean to add a Chan core instead of the `4.52m` inductor? Not lastly, have you tried using a non-unity coupling? Say... a good `0.995`? *devilish grin*

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Well, you re right ! I have the wish to simulate the TI reference design. This one : https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu248/tidu248.pdf?ts=1643010647685&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F. For the inductors, I set it like this for better clarity for me. One is the leakage inductance of the transformer and the other is the shim inductor of a PSFB necessary for having enough energy for achieving ZVS transition. But I could marry them :) I used Lp and Ls for setting via the ".param" a perfect transformer with a precise turn ratio.

Comment: I do not want to use a chan core model as I am not trying to observe effect of permeability on the design. But I want to see the effect of the magnetizing inductance. Theoritically it has an effet, that I have really some troubles to see on the simulation, on the transition time at certain step only depending if the transformer is short circuit at the secondary or not. But I have to spend more time to see what is really happening.

Comment: I do not tried to used a non unity coupling as I "added" a leakage inductance at the primary even if it is not exactly the same from my mind as the non unity coupling is probably something else than just a leakage inductance at the primary it also have an effect on magnetizing inductance. I think actually it probably also add leakage inductance at the secondaries too.. This was never clear to me ... And I would really appreciate if it could have a direct relation between K and magnetizing inductance/leakkage inductance at the primary and secondaries and perfect transformer

Comment: Nevertheless I will try as it seems to be devilish

Comment: Well it completely does not work but I do not what is really happening on the transformer when i do this " 0.995". The output voltage is completely not good ... It completely change the simulation ... Theoritically it should be 12V for around 0.7 dutycycle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133588/discussion-between-a-concerned-citizen-and-jess).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I need to make this an answer, to justify the copy-paste). You were right, congratulations for the detective eyes! Given the folow-up comments, I've added a separate section with diode rectification, and the plot shows the main difference between them. The missing bits to the right are the same as the middle part; it's just copy-paste:

[image: phase-shifted SMPS]

I've also made a 3rd section with MOSFETs (and reduced load/supply; not shown in the picture above), which shows the same negative current in the rectification. There are some side effects, too, such as oscillating output (the MOSFETs have parasitics, the VCSW don't), high frequency oscillations (same parasitics + the coupling is not 1), but the overall shape is there. Here is the whole thing, sorry for the aspect, but it was cropped in a haste, and updated in a similar manner. The lines will make all the difference, I'm sure...

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 1596 1840
WIRE 128 96 64 96
WIRE 272 96 128 96
WIRE 432 96 272 96
WIRE 496 96 432 96
WIRE 800 96 736 96
WIRE 880 96 800 96
WIRE 1104 96 880 96
WIRE 1168 96 1104 96
WIRE -480 128 -496 128
WIRE -384 128 -416 128
WIRE -288 128 -384 128
WIRE -176 128 -288 128
WIRE -288 160 -288 128
WIRE -272 160 -288 160
WIRE -176 160 -208 160
WIRE 128 176 128 160
WIRE 128 176 64 176
WIRE 432 176 432 160
WIRE 496 176 432 176
WIRE 800 176 800 160
WIRE 800 176 736 176
WIRE 1104 176 1104 160
WIRE 1168 176 1104 176
WIRE -496 192 -496 128
WIRE -416 192 -416 160
WIRE -416 192 -496 192
WIRE -192 192 -208 192
WIRE 64 192 64 176
WIRE 240 192 64 192
WIRE 496 192 496 176
WIRE 496 192 320 192
WIRE 736 192 736 176
WIRE 912 192 736 192
WIRE 1168 192 1168 176
WIRE 1168 192 992 192
WIRE 64 208 64 192
WIRE 128 208 64 208
WIRE 496 208 496 192
WIRE 496 208 432 208
WIRE 736 208 736 192
WIRE 800 208 736 208
WIRE 1168 208 1168 192
WIRE 1168 208 1104 208
WIRE -192 240 -192 192
WIRE -176 240 -192 240
WIRE -416 272 -416 192
WIRE -176 272 -416 272
WIRE 128 288 128 272
WIRE 128 288 64 288
WIRE 208 288 128 288
WIRE 432 288 432 272
WIRE 432 288 208 288
WIRE 496 288 432 288
WIRE 800 288 800 272
WIRE 800 288 736 288
WIRE 880 288 800 288
WIRE 1104 288 1104 272
WIRE 1104 288 880 288
WIRE 1168 288 1104 288
WIRE -384 352 -384 128
WIRE -368 352 -384 352
WIRE -288 352 -304 352
WIRE -176 352 -288 352
WIRE -288 384 -288 352
WIRE -272 384 -288 384
WIRE -176 384 -208 384
WIRE 304 400 80 400
WIRE 784 400 736 400
WIRE 880 400 848 400
WIRE 928 400 880 400
WIRE 1056 400 1008 400
WIRE 1104 400 1056 400
WIRE 1120 400 1104 400
WIRE -192 416 -208 416
WIRE 1120 448 1120 400
WIRE -192 464 -192 416
WIRE -176 464 -192 464
WIRE -304 496 -304 384
WIRE -176 496 -304 496
WIRE 80 512 80 480
WIRE 128 512 80 512
WIRE 416 512 208 512
WIRE 464 512 416 512
WIRE 480 512 464 512
WIRE 736 512 736 480
WIRE 768 512 736 512
WIRE 1056 512 1056 400
WIRE 80 544 80 512
WIRE 736 544 736 512
WIRE 480 560 480 512
WIRE 416 624 416 512
WIRE 784 624 736 624
WIRE 880 624 880 400
WIRE 880 624 848 624
WIRE 1056 640 1056 576
WIRE 1120 640 1120 528
WIRE 80 672 80 624
WIRE 144 672 80 672
WIRE 304 672 304 400
WIRE 304 672 240 672
WIRE 144 752 144 736
WIRE 144 752 80 752
WIRE 240 752 240 736
WIRE 240 752 144 752
WIRE 304 752 240 752
WIRE 416 752 416 688
WIRE 416 752 304 752
WIRE 480 752 480 640
WIRE 480 752 416 752
WIRE 912 832 736 832
WIRE -32 896 -208 896
WIRE 224 896 -32 896
WIRE -304 912 -368 912
WIRE -256 912 -304 912
WIRE 736 944 736 912
WIRE 784 944 736 944
WIRE 1200 944 864 944
WIRE 1248 944 1200 944
WIRE 1264 944 1248 944
WIRE -256 976 -256 912
WIRE 320 976 272 976
WIRE 384 976 320 976
WIRE 736 976 736 944
WIRE -304 992 -368 992
WIRE -208 992 -304 992
WIRE 1264 992 1264 944
WIRE -208 1056 -208 992
WIRE -32 1056 -208 1056
WIRE 224 1056 224 992
WIRE 224 1056 48 1056
WIRE 320 1056 224 1056
WIRE 384 1056 320 1056
WIRE 1200 1056 1200 944
WIRE -208 1088 -208 1056
WIRE 224 1088 224 1056
WIRE 736 1088 736 1056
WIRE 912 1088 912 832
WIRE -304 1168 -368 1168
WIRE -256 1168 -304 1168
WIRE 320 1168 272 1168
WIRE 384 1168 320 1168
WIRE 640 1168 576 1168
WIRE 688 1168 640 1168
WIRE 1008 1168 960 1168
WIRE 1072 1168 1008 1168
WIRE -304 1248 -368 1248
WIRE -208 1248 -208 1184
WIRE -208 1248 -304 1248
WIRE -64 1248 -208 1248
WIRE 224 1248 224 1184
WIRE 224 1248 -64 1248
WIRE 320 1248 224 1248
WIRE 384 1248 320 1248
WIRE 640 1248 576 1248
WIRE 736 1248 736 1184
WIRE 736 1248 640 1248
WIRE 912 1248 912 1184
WIRE 912 1248 736 1248
WIRE 1008 1248 912 1248
WIRE 1072 1248 1008 1248
WIRE 1200 1248 1200 1120
WIRE 1200 1248 1072 1248
WIRE 1264 1248 1264 1072
WIRE 1264 1248 1200 1248
FLAG 16 160 0
FLAG 16 272 0
FLAG 544 272 0
FLAG 544 160 0
FLAG 608 64 0
FLAG 208 288 0
FLAG -112 128 a
FLAG 16 112 a
FLAG 16 224 b
FLAG -112 240 b
FLAG -112 352 c
FLAG -112 464 d
FLAG 544 112 c
FLAG 544 224 d
FLAG 352 736 0
FLAG 352 688 f
FLAG 32 736 0
FLAG 32 688 e
FLAG -176 592 b
FLAG -176 624 c
FLAG -112 592 e
FLAG -176 688 a
FLAG -176 720 d
FLAG -112 688 f
FLAG 480 752 0
FLAG 464 512 o
FLAG 272 96 v
FLAG 688 160 0
FLAG 688 272 0
FLAG 1216 272 0
FLAG 1216 160 0
FLAG 880 288 0
FLAG 688 112 a
FLAG 688 224 b
FLAG 1216 112 c
FLAG 1216 224 d
FLAG 1120 640 0
FLAG 1104 400 o2
FLAG 768 512 0
FLAG 1056 640 0
FLAG -416 976 0
FLAG -416 1232 0
FLAG -64 1248 0
FLAG -416 928 a
FLAG -416 1184 b
FLAG 432 1184 d
FLAG 1120 1184 f
FLAG 528 1184 e
FLAG 1264 1248 0
FLAG 1248 944 o3
FLAG 528 1232 0
FLAG 1120 1232 0
FLAG 880 96 v
FLAG -32 896 v
FLAG 432 992 c
FLAG 432 1040 0
FLAG 432 1232 0
FLAG 608 -16 v
SYMBOL sw 64 192 M180
SYMATTR InstName S1
SYMBOL diode 112 160 M180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D1
SYMBOL sw 64 304 M180
SYMATTR InstName S2
SYMBOL diode 112 272 M180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D2
SYMBOL sw 496 192 R180
SYMATTR InstName S3
SYMBOL diode 448 160 R180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D3
SYMBOL sw 496 304 R180
SYMATTR InstName S4
SYMBOL diode 448 272 R180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D4
SYMBOL ind2 224 208 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 5 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName L1
SYMATTR Value 100u
SYMATTR Type ind
SYMBOL voltage 608 -32 R0
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value 100
SYMBOL Digital\\and -448 80 R0
WINDOW 3 -44 2 Left 2
SYMATTR Value td=5u ic=0
SYMATTR InstName A1
SYMBOL Digital\\and -240 112 R0
WINDOW 3 -23 108 Left 2
SYMATTR Value td=100n
SYMATTR InstName A2
SYMBOL Digital\\and -144 80 R0
WINDOW 3 -23 108 Left 2
SYMATTR Value tau=10n
SYMATTR InstName A3
SYMBOL Digital\\and -144 192 R0
WINDOW 3 -23 108 Left 2
SYMATTR Value tau=10n
SYMATTR InstName A4
SYMBOL Digital\\and -336 304 R0
WINDOW 3 -23 108 Left 2
SYMATTR Value td=4u
SYMATTR InstName A5
SYMBOL Digital\\and -240 336 R0
WINDOW 3 -23 108 Left 2
SYMATTR Value td=100n
SYMATTR InstName A6
SYMBOL Digital\\and -144 304 R0
WINDOW 3 -23 108 Left 2
SYMATTR Value tau=10n
SYMATTR InstName A7
SYMBOL Digital\\and -144 416 R0
WINDOW 3 -23 108 Left 2
SYMATTR Value tau=10n
SYMATTR InstName A8
SYMBOL ind2 96 496 R180
WINDOW 0 36 80 Left 2
WINDOW 3 36 40 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName L2
SYMATTR Value 100u
SYMATTR Type ind
SYMBOL ind2 96 640 R180
WINDOW 0 36 80 Left 2
WINDOW 3 36 40 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName L3
SYMATTR Value 100u
SYMATTR Type ind
SYMBOL sw 304 768 R180
SYMATTR InstName S5
SYMBOL diode 256 736 R180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D5
SYMBOL sw 80 768 M180
SYMATTR InstName S6
SYMBOL diode 128 736 M180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D6
SYMBOL Digital\\or -144 544 R0
WINDOW 3 -8 30 Left 2
SYMATTR Value tau=10n
SYMATTR InstName A9
SYMBOL ind2 112 528 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 5 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName La2
SYMATTR Value 10u
SYMATTR Type ind
SYMBOL cap 400 624 R0
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value 100u rser=10m
SYMBOL Digital\\or -144 640 R0
WINDOW 3 -8 30 Left 2
SYMATTR Value tau=10n
SYMATTR InstName A10
SYMBOL res 464 544 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 10
SYMBOL sw 736 192 M180
SYMATTR InstName S7
SYMBOL diode 784 160 M180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D7
SYMBOL sw 736 304 M180
SYMATTR InstName S8
SYMBOL diode 784 272 M180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D8
SYMBOL sw 1168 192 R180
SYMATTR InstName S9
SYMBOL diode 1120 160 R180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D9
SYMBOL sw 1168 304 R180
SYMATTR InstName S10
SYMBOL diode 1120 272 R180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D10
SYMBOL ind2 896 208 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 5 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName L4
SYMATTR Value 100u
SYMATTR Type ind
SYMBOL ind2 752 496 R180
WINDOW 0 36 80 Left 2
WINDOW 3 36 40 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName L5
SYMATTR Value 100u
SYMATTR Type ind
SYMBOL ind2 752 640 R180
WINDOW 0 36 80 Left 2
WINDOW 3 36 40 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName L6
SYMATTR Value 100u
SYMATTR Type ind
SYMBOL diode 784 416 R270
WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName D11
SYMBOL diode 784 608 M90
WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName D12
SYMBOL ind2 912 416 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 5 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName La1
SYMATTR Value 10u
SYMATTR Type ind
SYMBOL cap 1040 512 R0
SYMATTR InstName C2
SYMATTR Value 100u rser=10m
SYMBOL res 1104 432 R0
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 10
SYMBOL ind2 -48 1072 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 5 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName L7
SYMATTR Value 100u
SYMATTR Type ind
SYMBOL ind2 752 928 R180
WINDOW 0 36 80 Left 2
WINDOW 3 36 40 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName L8
SYMATTR Value 100u
SYMATTR Type ind
SYMBOL ind2 752 1072 R180
WINDOW 0 36 80 Left 2
WINDOW 3 36 40 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName L9
SYMATTR Value 100u
SYMATTR Type ind
SYMBOL ind2 768 960 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 5 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName La3
SYMATTR Value 10u
SYMATTR Type ind
SYMBOL cap 1184 1056 R0
SYMATTR InstName C3
SYMATTR Value 100u rser=10m
SYMBOL res 1248 976 R0
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value 10
SYMBOL nmos 688 1088 R0
SYMATTR InstName M1
SYMATTR Value IPB107N20N3
SYMBOL nmos 960 1088 M0
WINDOW 3 57 51 Left 2
SYMATTR Value IPB107N20N3
SYMATTR InstName M2
SYMBOL g 576 1152 R0
SYMATTR InstName G1
SYMATTR Value 12
SYMBOL res 624 1152 R0
SYMATTR InstName R4
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL g 1072 1152 M0
SYMATTR InstName G2
SYMATTR Value 12
SYMBOL res 1024 1152 M0
SYMATTR InstName R5
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL nmos 272 1088 M0
WINDOW 3 57 51 Left 2
SYMATTR Value IPB107N20N3
SYMATTR InstName M3
SYMBOL nmos 272 896 M0
WINDOW 3 57 51 Left 2
SYMATTR Value IPB107N20N3
SYMATTR InstName M4
SYMBOL g 384 960 M0
SYMATTR InstName G3
SYMATTR Value 12
SYMBOL res 336 960 M0
SYMATTR InstName R6
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL g 384 1152 M0
SYMATTR InstName G4
SYMATTR Value 12
SYMBOL res 336 1152 M0
SYMATTR InstName R7
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL nmos -256 1088 R0
WINDOW 3 57 51 Left 2
SYMATTR Value IPB107N20N3
SYMATTR InstName M5
SYMBOL nmos -256 896 R0
WINDOW 3 57 51 Left 2
SYMATTR Value IPB107N20N3
SYMATTR InstName M6
SYMBOL g -368 896 R0
SYMATTR InstName G5
SYMATTR Value 12
SYMBOL res -320 896 R0
SYMATTR InstName R8
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL g -368 1152 R0
SYMATTR InstName G6
SYMATTR Value 12
SYMBOL res -320 1152 R0
SYMATTR InstName R9
SYMATTR Value 1
TEXT -376 0 Left 2 !.model sw sw ron=50m roff=0.1g vt=0.5 vh=-0.5 ; level=2 oneway ilimit=1k\n.model d d ron=50m roff=0.1g vfwd=0.45 vrev=1k epsilon=50m revepsilon=1
TEXT 392 336 Left 2 !k l1 l2 l3 0.99
TEXT 376 440 Left 2 !.tran 1m
TEXT -472 -152 Left 2 ;https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucc28950.pdf?ts=1642537671521&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FUCC28950\nhttps://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucc2895.pdf?ts=1642523455070&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FUCC2895\nhttps://training.ti.com/how-design-multi-kw-dcdc-converters-electric-vehicles-evs-how-psfb-works
TEXT 368 392 Left 2 ;.save v(o)
TEXT 1000 344 Left 2 !k2 l4 l5 l6 0.99
TEXT 1016 848 Left 2 !k3 l7 l8 l9 0.99
LINE Normal -48 816 -48 64 2
LINE Normal 624 816 624 112 2
LINE Normal 1376 816 -336 816 2
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I will take a look on it tomorrow :D I am wondering what is the man underneath "a concerned citizen". But you could answer : " This is not who I am underneath that defines me ... But what I do...." https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WW1a_cNKapY. There is still the question :  Why each windings have just not "(Iout+deltaIout)/2" current value ? I wil probably find the answer into your simulation :)

Comment: @Jess I have to confess that these beasts are new to me, and if I change values on the load side RLC, the VCSW and the MOSFET versions show results that differ in certain areas. What you say seems to be true for the diode rectification. I'll try to read and poke around some more. And underneath me is my neighbour, I'll send your regards...

Comment: I don't know what else to say, since no other answer came up, but I'm hoping you realize you're not looking where you need to look. In your 1st picture after edit (LTspice sim) the cursors are at the *end*, when the body diode conducts, but the 2nd picture you're showing below, from TI, with the yellow marks, points at the *beginning* (follow the arrow). That part that is zoomed in, pointed at with the 2nd arrow, shows that inverse conduction, where your cursors are, and they're due to the overlapping controls of the SR.

Comment: You re right ;)