# LTspice giving weird results in simulation of phase shifted full bridge converter

Tags: power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, ltspice, simulation, simulink

I am trying to simulate a phase shifted full bridge converter in LTspice. I had already simulated it in MATLAB Simulink and obtained the desired results, but I am redoing it in LTspice to include the effects of non-ideal components.

In order to avoid the pulse generation, I imported the switching pulses datapoints from Simulink. I have thoroughly checked it and there's no issue with my switching pulses. However, the same circuit in LTspice behaves very weirdly.

This is my model:

[image]

First of all the current on primary is weirdly high, around 3kA where as it is 25A peak in Simulink. The current wave on primary side is as shown below:

[image]

This is the output DC waveform (I am expecting a stable DC of around 85V as I had obtained in Simulink.)

[image]

I suspect it is an issue with the transformer, but I am not able to pin-point it exactly. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Question - why does your circuit not have an output capacitor?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding either a ground, or some `1meg` to ground, to the primary side. Just because it works it doesn't mean that it should be this way. Also to the individual controlling sources. In SPICE, all nodes need a reference to ground, otherwise a floating node could have any voltage, which will cause problems for the matrix solver (what voltage should it use?). LTspice cheats a bit (tries to help users that don't know) by adding some `Gmin` to the floating nodes, but that doesn't mean you should accept the results, or even form a reflex out of it.

Also, the `Ron` for the diode might be a bit too high, try this:

```
.model d d ron=10m roff=10meg vfwd=0.4 vrev=200 epsilon=0.1 revepsilon=1
```

Comment: Also see [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/605833/95619).